Add to TOC some section of table
I use a long table "longtblr" which spreads on 5 pages. The table is under \section.
The table has several topics with many parameters : that means 10 rows about ITEM_a , and 30 rows about ITEM_b, ....
From TOC I can arrive only to the beginning of the table. And for example needed topic is in the end of the table, I need to scroll down 5 pages.
How can I add to the table links or subsection , which will appear in TOC under main section ?
Thank you in advance.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{longtable}
\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Gubert Farnsworth}
\date{ }
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}


\begin{longtable}[c]{| c | c |}
\caption{Long table caption.\label{long}}\\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{Begin of Table}\\
 \hline
 Something & something else\\
 \hline
 \endfirsthead

 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Continuation of Table \ref{long}}\\
 \hline
 Something & something else\\
 \hline
 \endhead

 \hline
 \endfoot

 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{End of Table}\\
 \hline\hline
 \endlastfoot

 ITEM\_a         & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
ITEM\_b             & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
ITEM\_c           & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
ITEM\_d           & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
ITEM\_e           & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
 \end{longtable}


\section{Second Section}

\blindtext
\end{document}


Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

I added an example

But it does not compile without error and therefore isn't a MWE. Please correct it. Also the screenshot is not from the shown code and the shown code would not add a subsection entry "Table" to the ToC. So it is unclear whether you want the items in the ToC or the LoT.

Sorry, forgot "" before "_", fixed. I deleted the picture to not confuse

In the question text, you are talking about "longtblr", but in the example you are using longtable. Note, longtblr is an environment of tabularray. Using this term instead of longtable for other tables is confusing and therefore not recommended. And your example also does not use hyperref. So the tags hyperref and cross-referencing also seem to be wrong here.

It is quite unclear, why you want the ITEM_… in the table of contents instead of the list of tables, but you are the boss …
As usual you can use \addcontentsline to add entries to the table of contents. In your case it would make most sense to use the subsection level, so you should use
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{ITEM\_a}

etc.
I would also suggest to use a command to generate the items:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Gubert Farnsworth}
\date{ }

\newcommand*\ITEM[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{ITEM\_#1}% ToC entry
  ITEM\_#1% item
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}


\begin{longtable}[c]{| c | c |}
\caption{Long table caption.\label{long}}\\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{Begin of Table}\\
 \hline
 Something & something else\\
 \hline
 \endfirsthead

 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Continuation of Table \ref{long}}\\
 \hline
 Something & something else\\
 \hline
 \endhead

 \hline
 \endfoot

 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{End of Table}\\
 \hline\hline
 \endlastfoot

 \ITEM{a}         & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
\ITEM{b}             & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
\ITEM{c}           & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
\ITEM{d}           & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
\ITEM{e}           & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
                 & like this\\
 \end{longtable}


\section{Second Section}

\blindtext
\end{document}


Just an opinion: Such tables with lots of vertical an horizontal lines are not only ugly but also typographically questionable. For tables with two columns and a kind of (numerated) items, often an enumeration list using package enumitem is the better solution.
